# maps function gives 6 array on console and won't output separate arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm still trying to navigate inside the `map` function but still need a little bit of help.

I'm trying to to gather all `storeArea` values in one individual array, and all `totalStore.date` values into different individual array.
when I'm using `map` im getting for `totalStore.date` 6 arrays within an object. whats the right and correct thing to do?
Thanks!

```
var results =[]

var stores_json = {
"stores": [
  {
    "storeArea": "area1",
    "totalStore": [
      {
        "date": "2018-10-01"
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-11-01"
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-12-01"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "storeArea": "area2",
    "totalStore": [
      {
        "date": "2018-10-01"
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-11-01"
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-12-01"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "storeArea": "area3",
    "totalStore": [
      {
        "date": "2018-10-01"
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-11-01"
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-12-01"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "storeArea": "area4",
    "totalStore": [
      {
        "date": "2018-10-01"
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-11-01"
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-12-01"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "storeArea": "area5",
    "totalStore": [
      {
        "date": "2018-10-01"
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-11-01"
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-12-01"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "storeArea": "area6",
    "totalStore": [
      {
        "date": "2018-10-01"
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-11-01"
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-12-01"
      }
    ]
  }
]
}

results = stores_json["stores"].map(function (x) {
    return [x.storeArea, x.totalStore.map(function (y) {
        var dates = [y.date]
        return dates
    })]
});
```

Comment: I edited the question. I need all `date` values in one single array and the same for storeArea. sorry for the mixup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
areas = json.stores.map(function (x) {
    return x.storeArea
});
dates = json.stores.map(function (x) {
    return x.totalStore.map(function (y) {
        return y.date
    })
});
results = [areas,dates.flat()]
```

results is -

```
(2) [Array(6), Array(18)]
0: (6) ["area1", "area2", "area3", "area4", "area5", "area6"]
1: (18) ["2018-10-01", "2018-11-01", "2018-12-01", "2018-10-01", "2018-11-01", "2018-12-01", "2018-10-01", "2018-11-01", "2018-12-01", "2018-10-01", "2018-11-01", "2018-12-01", "2018-10-01", "2018-11-01", "2018-12-01", "2018-10-01", "2018-11-01", "2018-12-01"]
```

Comment: that's exactly what i needed. Thank you!